# Create variable that is mean of group

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

I am working with a large survey dataset, comprised of several countries and years. I am trying to create a new variable that is the mean trust score of each country in a particular year. I want to create a line graph showing the patterns of trust for each country across the years. I have a variable which is 'country years' which determines the country and the year of the survey.
When I use the code below, I just get a variable which has the overall mean of all trust scores, rather than specific country_year mean trust scores.

```
data<-data%>%
  group_by(country_year)%>%
  mutate(averagetrust = mean(trust))

My dataset looks something like this, but with 31 countries and 342 country/year combinations. The trust scores are individual trust scores for each respondents

#     country  year country_year  trust
# 1   Austria  2002  AT2002       4
# 2   Austria  2002  AT2002       9
# 55  Belgium  2002  BE2002       7
# 56  Belgium  2002  BE2002       3
# 91  Austria  2005  AT2005       2
# 91  Austria  2005  AT2005       6
# 141 Belgium  2005  BE2005       5
# 142 Belgium  2005  BE2005       9
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. While it is clear what you are trying to achieve your question lacks the necessary details to figure out what's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my question to include a snippet of what my data looks like

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `summarise`

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

gapminder%>%
  group_by(country, year)%>%
  filter(country %in% c("Germany", "Belgium", "France")) %>% 
  summarise(averagetrust = mean(pop, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = averagetrust, color = country)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: When I do I just get the overall mean trust

Comment: `averagetrust
<dbl>
4.401746`

Comment: I edited it with an example from gapminder which is also a year-country panel.

Comment: I am able to calculate the means for each country year but I cannot attach them as a variable in my dataset, when I do I get this error message ```Error:
! Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 366816 rows.
x Assigned data has 349 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Backtrace:
  1. base::`$<-`(`*tmp*`, avgtrust, value = `<tibble[,2]>`)
 14. tibble `<fn>`(`<vctrs___>`)```